# Gradle tasks dependency

Tags: gradle, groovy, build.gradle, gradlew

**Q:** Can one task be dependent on another task **with specific argument**? If the answer is yes then how to accomplish that?

---

I opened Gradle for myself recently, and just got curious about next:

Let's say I'd like to have one of the **build**'s subfolders to be copied each time I execute the `copy` task.

```
task copy (type: Copy) {
    dependsOn build 
    from '[fromName]'
    into '[intoName]'
}
```

In my case, I'd like to copy folder **build/reports/profile**, but the thing is that this folder is created by execution of the `build --profile` task.

So, is there any chance to accomplish the following:

```
task copy (...) {
    dependsOn build --profile
    from ...
    into ...
}
```

Btw, plugin `project-report` doesn't create this folder, to be dependent on its task.

**Note**: It's not as important to have it done, I'm just interested if it is possible at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass arguments with `dependsOn` to a task directly but you can create a custom `Exec` task and pass arguments via the command line interpreter (cmd) using the gradle wrapper like this:

```
task buildWithArgument(type: Exec) {
    commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 'gradlew.bat build --profile'
}

task copy (type: Copy) {
    dependsOn buildWithArgument
    from '[fromName]'
    into '[intoName]'
}
```